# Online Sources of Reviews of MTB bicycles in INDIA

Tags: mountain-bike

I am from India and planning to buy a MTB bicycle. My budget is around Rs. 7k - 8k.
I am confused between the two ranges

1. Hero Octane
2. Hercules Roadeo

Can someone suggest me any good sites for bicycle reviews in India, or suggest me which brand would be better than the other.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're going to be able to get any good answers the way that the question is phrased. Which one is "better" is a subjective question. Better for what? Downhill biking? Cross Country? Getting to work? Furthermore, SE sites tend to be hesitant at best to provide shopping recommendations. It's better if you ask what characteristics you should look for when shopping for a bike for a given purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some quick Googling I was able to determine that 7k-8k rupees is equivalent to an $130 to $150 USD price range.  It seems that the bikes you are looking at are full suspension mountain bikes, and look pretty similar to the bikes sold in department stores in the US. Bikes in this price range are generally not found on review sites because they are pretty much bottom of the line, and there isn't much good that can be said about them.

For that price range you are much better off buying a used bike that is of much better quality.  If you want to buy new, I would stay away from the full suspension mountain bikes because the suspension isn't that good anyway and the money you'll save from the lack of suspension means the rest of the bike will be better quality.  Plus you'll probably save quite a bit on weight.

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives you could consider at that price point

- Rockrider 5.0
- Hercules ACT 110 Steel
- Firefox Cyclone

A good second hand bike is a good option too - http://www.bumsonthesaddle.com/marketplace

Buy a simple bike and avoid buying bicycles with suspensions in this range.
More details - http://help.bumsonthesaddle.com